# Dimiss two ViewControllers one after the another:iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to dismiss two view controllers one after the another, 
In my first view controller I have kept uploading feature, which when completes the current view controller is dismissed.

Now, after the uploading ViewController is dismissed,I come to previous viewcontroller. I want to dismiss that "previousViewController" as well.

After the "uploadViewController" is dismissed, I call method on "PreviousViewController"

Here is how I am trying to do it:

In UploadViewController:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

            [previousView dismissME];
        }];
```

And now when I come to "PreviousViewController"

Here is that `dismissME` method:

```
-(void)dismissME {

    if (![[self presentingViewController] isBeingDismissed]) {
        NSLog(@"Dismiss ME");
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

I get that "Dismiss ME" log, but the viewController is not being dismissed.

Any ideas .. ? How to achieve this ..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code helps in dismissing the previous two viewcontrollers.

```
[[[self presentingViewController] presentingViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for .. !! 
Thanks @Vinayak Kini.

Answer (score 3):

1) create a variable called parent in the **uploadViewController.h** like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController *parent;
```

2) set the parent of **uploadViewController** self when it presented from the **PreviousViewController** like this:

```
    uploadViewController *controller = [[uploadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"uploadViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.parent = self;
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

3) define a method in **PreviousViewController** to dismiss the View like this:

```
- (void) dismissView{
    NSLog(@"Dismiss");
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

4) call that method when dismissing the **uploadViewController** like this,

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [(ParentModeViewController *)_parent dismissView];
    }];
```

I tested it and it works fine for me, Hope it will help you

Comment: I will also suggest you to check out Vinayak Kini's answer below, Its a one liner.. and does the job I need it to do.

Comment: yeh saw that and I highly recommend to use that answer :) I didn't know that you could dismiss a view like that!! I noted that answer in my helper class :P

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
   -(void)myDismiss {
       [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   }


   -(void)dismissME {
       if (![[self presentingViewController] isBeingDismissed]) {
           NSLog(@"Dismiss ME");
           [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.8 target:self selector:@selector(myDismiss) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
       }
   }
```

**Edit**
       try with viewDidAppear method of PreviousViewController

```
    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
       [super viewDidAppear:animated];
       [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.8 target:self selector:@selector(myDismiss) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
   }
```

if it doesn't work then increased  scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval. and if it work then decreased scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval to 0.7,0.6...

Comment: Nop, doesnt work :(
Did not work for time interval of one second.

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
[self.parentViewController.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Should i put this method is dismissME ?

Comment: call this in UploadViewController

Answer (score 0):

You need to dismiss uploadViewController first and then PreviousViewController. Do the following code:

```
-(void)dismissView{

    UIViewController *vc = [self parentViewController];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [vc dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Hope this code will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

try and check if you add the view controller multiple times say in a loop or something so that even if you remove one instance another instance of the view controller remains.